# Не могу разобраться с запуском приложения через библиотеку Python Eel

Tags: python, eel

Сам файл горит желтым в Визуал студии.

```
import eel
eel.init("web")

eel.start('index.html', mode="chrome", port=0 , size=(1280,512))`

PS C:\Users\Сергей\Desktop\Application> python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    eel.start('index.html', mode="chrome", port=0 , size=(1280,512))
  File "C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\eel\__init__.py", line 174, in start
    show(*start_urls)
  File "C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\eel\__init__.py", line 206, in show 
    brw.open(list(start_urls), _start_args)
  File "C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\eel\browsers.py", line 75, in open
    browser_module.run(path, options, start_urls)
  File "C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\eel\chrome.py", line 15, in run
    sps.Popen([path, '--app=%s' % url] +
  File "C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл
PS C:\Users\Сергей\Desktop\Application>
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться и понять в чем ошибка.

1. Библиотеку переустанавливал много раз
2. Искал в документации ответы, не нашел, а что нашел не помогло

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос минимальный код, или хотя бы  покажите что у Вас в 3-ей строке (перед eel.start) и желательно структуру папок проекта. (Кириллицу в путях давно не использую поэтому не знаю может ли это быть причиной ошибки)

Comment: Полное имя компьютера, какое?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка причиненная тем, что у вас

1. или нет папки с именем `web` в папке `C:\Users\Сергей\Desktop\Application`,
2. или такая папка существует, но в ней нету файла `index.html`.

---

Проверите так, что вы двойным кликом на иконе `Application` откроите ее содержание.

- Когда там нет папки `web`, нужно ее создать.
- Когда есть (или когда вы ее уже создали), двойным кликом ее откройте. Вы увидите, что в ней нет файла `index.html`, нужно эго создать (или скопировать уже приготовленный файл из неправильной папки).